# VSCode Python/Pylance does not gray out unaccessed variable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

In below screenshot when hovering over the grayed out variables Pylance (correctly!) says they are not accessed, e.g.; `"_baz" is not accessed Pylance`. My question is about `waz`, which is clearly not accessed in either tabs, still not grayed out. Why isn't it grayed out?

[image]

I thought maybe it was related to `waz` not being a "private" (underscore) variable, but it just doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables without an underscore are considered public, so it might be used when imported from somewhere else.

Comment: Very interesting. So it is not grayed out intentionally and then this is a feature, not a bug, right? Pylance assumes - that since being global and public - other modules might import it and it can be used somewhere else? An incorrect gray coloring could mislead me in this module and I would probably delete the variable here, not knowing that I accidentally broke other modules importing this one

Comment: @AndrasVanyolos Yes.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio Code even when you use pylance the unused variable will not be grayed out. although when you add the underscore(_) it grays out because it's private.
Here are some pictures showing that:

first picture: Look at the unused available "art" and the unused private variable "_waz"

[image: "]

second Picture: "When I use the variable '_waz', the text is displayed in color."

[image: Look here at "_waz" when I use it's coloured]

Brief: to gray out a variable you have to make it private by putting an underscore or use it as a parameter, else the variables will be displayed in color.

That answer is referenced by my experience in using Pylance for 3 years

Comment: hmmm, I don't understand this. First, your screenshots are exactly the same. Second, I think `_baz` is grayed out because it is not referenced, and not because it is "private". And your `art` is exactly as my `waz`, a "non-private" unaccessed variable and still NOT grayed out - no idea why...